# Buffer overflow doesn't run

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb, buffer-overflow

I try an basic buffer overflow, i overwrite the saved EIP on the stack an jump on to the adress. This adress point to à shell variable who containt my shellcode.

But on gdb, program sigserv on the first nop on the nopslide.

I lauch th program like this command:

```
gdb-peda$ r $(python -c 'print "A"*22 + "\x5f\xb8\xff\xff"')
```

I have this trace:

```
[----------------------------------registers-----------------------------------]
EAX: 0x1a 
EBX: 0xf7fc3ff4 --> 0x15dd7c 
ECX: 0xffffaf38 --> 0xf7fc44e0 --> 0xfbad2a84 
EDX: 0xf7fc5360 --> 0x0 
ESI: 0x0 
EDI: 0x0 
EBP: 0x41414141 ('AAAA')
ESP: 0xffffaf80 --> 0xffffb100 --> 0xc ('\x0c')
EIP: 0xffffb85f --> 0x90909090
EFLAGS: 0x10296 (carry PARITY ADJUST zero SIGN trap INTERRUPT direction overflow)
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]
   0xffffb85c:  nop
   0xffffb85d:  nop
   0xffffb85e:  nop
=> 0xffffb85f:  nop
   0xffffb860:  nop
   0xffffb861:  nop
   0xffffb862:  nop
   0xffffb863:  nop
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]
0000| 0xffffaf80 --> 0xffffb100 --> 0xc ('\x0c')
0004| 0xffffaf84 --> 0xf7fef060 (push   ebp)
0008| 0xffffaf88 --> 0x80484bb (<__libc_csu_init+11>:   add    ebx,0x1219)
0012| 0xffffaf8c --> 0xf7fc3ff4 --> 0x15dd7c 
0016| 0xffffaf90 --> 0x80484b0 (<__libc_csu_init>:  push   ebp)
0020| 0xffffaf94 --> 0x0 
0024| 0xffffaf98 --> 0xffffb018 --> 0x0 
0028| 0xffffaf9c --> 0xf7e7ce46 (<__libc_start_main+230>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax)
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
Legend: code, data, rodata, value
Stopped reason: SIGSEGV
0xffffb85f in ?? ()
gdb-peda$ x/i $eip
=> 0xffffb85f:  nop
```

I run on debian wheezy, gcc version is gcc (Debian 4.7.2-4) 4.7.2, gdb version 7.4.1-debian.

Is an new protection on this gcc version? Or other think?

Thanks you. (Sorry for my english :))

Comment: Did my answer help? If so, then can you select it as "accepted answer", by clicking next to it, so the question will be moved from unanswered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove stack protection by following any of these steps:

[Illustration of buffer overflows for students (linux, C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649089/illustration-of-buffer-overflows-for-students-linux-c)